# Apply function to subsets of a sequence generated by dropping the head incrementally

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, functional-programming

## Intro

Let's say I have the following sequence:

```
var ls = new[]{10, 20, 30, 40};
```

I'd like to apply a function to:

- The entire sequence
- The entire sequence except the first
- The entire sequence except the second
- ...

## Implementation

Here's one approach to implementing this:

```
IEnumerable<U> f_a<T,U>(IEnumerable<T> seq, Func<IEnumerable<T>, U> proc) =>
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, seq.Count())
        .Select(n => seq.Skip(n))
        .Select(proc);
```

## Examples

Example: join the subsets:

[image]

Example: sum the subsets:

[image]

Example: sum the subsets and show the seq:

[image]

(Examples generated in [dotnet-interactive](https://github.com/dotnet/interactive) in vscode.)

## Question

Is there already a built-in function that basically performs `f_a` above?

If not, would you recommend another approach to implementing `f_a`?

Does the equivalent of `f_a` exist in libraries from other languages?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware that there's anything exactly like that in the .NET base class library, although I'm fairly sure that you could implement it with [Aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate).

In Haskell, the first part of the function is available in the *base* library as the [tails](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-List.html#v:tails) function. It takes a sequence of values and "returns all final segments of the argument, longest first".

Since functional values are composable, there's no reason to make a building block (function) more complicated than that. If you want to apply a function to each of the subsets, you simple map over each of them. In C#, assuming that you have a similar `Tails` extension method, you can implement the above examples like this:

```
[Fact]
public void Join()
{
    var ls = new[] { 10, 20, 30, 40 };
    var actual = ls.Tails().Select(seq => string.Join(",", seq));
    Assert.Equal(new[] { "10,20,30,40", "20,30,40", "30,40", "40" }, actual);
}

[Fact]
public void Sum()
{
    var ls = new[] { 10, 20, 30, 40 };
    var actual = ls.Tails().Select(seq => seq.Sum());
    Assert.Equal(new[] { 100, 90, 70, 40 }, actual);
}

[Fact]
public void SubsetAndSum()
{
    var ls = new[] { 10, 20, 30, 40 };
    var actual = ls.Tails().Select(seq => (seq, seq.Sum()));
    Assert.Equal<IEnumerable<(IEnumerable<int> seq, int)>>(
        new[] {
            (new[] { 10, 20, 30, 40 }.AsEnumerable(), 100),
            (new[] { 20, 30, 40 }, 90),
            (new[] { 30, 40 }, 70),
            (new[] { 40 }, 40)
        },
        actual);
}
```

These examples use [xUnit.net](https://xunit.net).

You can implement `Tails` as an extension method like sketched in the OP, but I also think that other implementation options are possible.

Comment: Great answer Mark, thank you. And thank you for pointing out `tails` from Haskell.